# Multiple keypresses not working properly in games

Tags: keyboard, wine, games, steam

I have an issue with my keyboard on Ubuntu 13.10 but this has been going on since 9.10.  I tried to test on a Wine game (Mass Effect 3) and on a native Linux game (Left for Dead 2 on Steam) both with similar issues.

If I press `W` to move forward and press `A` or `D` to strafe (while still holding down `W`) and then let go of `A` or `D`, the transmission of `W` to move forward simply halts.

I have Repeat Keys enabled (Key presses repeat when key is held down) and I'm not certain what is causing my issues.

For what its worth, my keyboard is a PS/2 keyboard hooked up into a USB adapter.  The model number is: Logitech Y-SZ49.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by my PS/2 USB adapter as the keyboard functions correctly on other machines running Ubuntu.